# someone guide me a code i want to write a procedure in sql oracle which take input from user and tell this input is character or not

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create or replace procedure check_chracter
Declare x char
x:= "enter_value"
as begin
if( (x>='a' and x<='z') or (x>='A' and x<='Z'))

    print"number is character";    
else
print"number is not character";
end;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `REGEXP_LIKE` and `PROMPT` command which works in SQL* Plus , SQL developer like editors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_chracter(
     p_in VARCHAR2)
as BEGIN
 IF regexp_like(p_in,'^[a-zA-Z]$') then
      dbms_output.put_line( 'value is a character');   
    ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line( 'value is not a character');
 END IF;
END;
```

Execution

```
set serveroutput on
ACCEPT x PROMPT 'enter value: '
exec check_chracter('&x');
```

Output

```
enter value: 3
SQL> exec check_chracter('&x')
value is not a character

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


enter value: q
SQL> exec check_chracter('&x')
value is a character

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: @nikhilsugandh : Nope. It matches a single alphabetic character **only**. Have a closer look.

Answer (score 1):

this will work in `sql developer`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE abc
    (p1 in varchar2)
AS
  BEGIN
    if(ascii(p1)>=65 and ascii(p1)<=90) then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('its a character');
    elsif(ascii(p1)>=97 and ascii(p1)<=122) then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('its a character');
    else 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('its a  not a character');

    end if;

    END;
/
set serveroutput on;
declare
p1 varchar(20);
p2 varchar(20);
begin
select :a into p1 from dual;
abc (p1);
end;
/
```

Comment: ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
ORA-06550: line 1, column 25:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ;
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:  ya error aa rahaa hai